# izip_longest in itertools: what's going on here?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm struggeling to understand how the below code works. It's from http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest, and is the pure-python equivalent of the izip_longest iterator. I'm especially mystified by the sentinel function, how does it work?

```
def izip_longest(*args, **kwds):
    # izip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
    def sentinel(counter = ([fillvalue]*(len(args)-1)).pop):
        yield counter()         # yields the fillvalue, or raises IndexError
    fillers = repeat(fillvalue)
    iters = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
    try:
        for tup in izip(*iters):
            yield tup
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, we can do this. About the sentinel. The expression `([fillvalue]*(len(args)-1))` creates a list that contains one fill value for each iterable in `args`, minus one. So, for the example above `['-']`. `counter` is then assigned the [`pop`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)-function of that list. `sentinel` itself is a [generator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) that pops one item from that list on each iteration. You can iterate over each iterator returned by `sentinel` exactly once, and it will always yield `fillvalue`. The total number of items yielded by all iterators returned by `sentinel` is `len(args) - 1` (thanks to Sven Marnach for clarifying that, I misunderstood it).

Now check out this:

```
iters = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
```

That is the trick. `iters` is a list that contains an iterator for each iterable in `args`. Each of these iterators does the following:

1. Iterate over all items in the corresponding iterable from `args`.
2. Iterate over sentinel once, yielding `fillvalue`.
3. Repeat `fillvalue` for all eternity.

Now, as established earlier, we can only iterate over all sentinels together `len(args)-1` times before it throws an `IndexError`. This is fine, because one of the iterables is the longest. So, when we come to the point that the `IndexError` is raised, that means we have finished iterating over the longest iterable in `args`.

You are welcome.

P.S.: I hope this is understandable.

Comment: In addition, `sentinel()` can be called an infinite number of times without any exception raised.

Answer (score 5):

The function `sentinel()` returns iterators yielding `fillvalue` exactly once.  The total number of `fillvalue`s yielded by all iterators returned by `sentinel()` is limited to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of iterators passed to `izip_longest()`.  After this number of `fillvalue`s has been exhausted, further iteration over an iterator returned by `sentinel()` will raise an `IndexError`.

This function is used to detect whether all iterators have been exhausted:  Each iterator is `chain()`ed with an iterator returned by `sentinel()`.  If all iterators are exhausted, an iterator returned by `sentinel()` will get iterated over for the `n`th time, resulting in an `IndexError`, triggering the end of `izip_longest()` in turn.

So far I explained what `sentinel()` does, not how it works.  When `izip_longest()` is called, the definition of `sentinel()` is evaluated.  While evaluating the definition, also the default argument to `sentinel()` is evaluated, once per call to `izip_longest()`.  The code is equivalent to

```
fillvalue_list = [fillvalue] * (len(args)-1)
def sentinel():
    yield fillvalue_list.pop()
```

Storing this in a default argument instead of in a variable in an enclosing scope is just an optimisation, as is the inclusion of `.pop` in the default argument, since it save looking it up every time an iterator returned by `sentinel()` is iterated over.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `sentinel` is almost equivalent to

```
def sentinel():
    yield ([fillvalue] * (len(args) - 1)).pop()
```

except that it gets the `pop` bound method (a function object) as a default argument. A default argument is evaluated at the time of function definition, so once per call to `izip_longest` instead of once per call to `sentinel`. Therefore, the function object "remembers" the list `[fillvalue] * (len(args) - 1)` instead of constructing this anew in every call.