# izip_longest in itertools: How does rasing IndexError inside the iterator work?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298705/izip-longest-in-itertools-whats-going-on-here) question @lazyr asks how the following code of `izip_longest` iterator from [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.izip_longest) works:

```
def izip_longest_from_docs(*args, **kwds):
    # izip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
    def sentinel(counter = ([fillvalue]*(len(args)-1)).pop):
        yield counter()         # yields the fillvalue, or raises IndexError
    fillers = repeat(fillvalue)
    iters = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
    try:
        for tup in izip(*iters):
            yield tup
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

When I was trying to understand how it works I stumbled into the question:
"What if `IndexError` is raised inside one of those iterators that are sent to `izip_longest` as parameters?".

Then I wrote some testing code:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, repeat, chain, izip

def izip_longest_from_docs(*args, **kwds):
    # The code is exactly the same as shown above
    ....

def gen1():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

def gen2():
    for i in range(10):
        if i==8:
            raise IndexError #simulation IndexError raised inside the iterator
        yield i

for i in izip_longest_from_docs(gen1(),gen2(), fillvalue = '-'):
    print('{i[0]} {i[1]}'.format(**locals()))

print('\n')

for i in izip_longest(gen1(),gen2(), fillvalue = '-'):
    print('{i[0]} {i[1]}'.format(**locals()))
```

And it turned out that the function in `itertools` module and `izip_longest_from_docs` work differently.

The output of the code above:

```
>>> 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
- 5
- 6
- 7


0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/..., line 31, in <module>
    for i in izip_longest(gen1(),gen2(), fillvalue = '-'):
  File "C:/... test_IndexError_inside iterator.py", line 23, in gen2
    raise IndexError
IndexError
```

So, it's clearly seen, that the code of `izip_longes` from `itertools` did propagate `IndexError` exception (as I think it should), but `izip_longes_from_docs` 'swallowed' `IndexError` exception as it took it as a signal from `sentinel` to stop iterating.

My question is, how did they worked around `IndexError` propagation in the code in the`itertools` module?

Comment: @agf I wanted, but I couldn't find it. Thanks for the link! I will give it a look.

Comment: @agf It seems to be in C :o) A bit too complicated for me. Nevertheless, what alleged to be an **equivalent** doesn't seem to be an absolute equivalent in terms of functionality (not speed).

Comment: Yep, you're correct. "If you find a bug in this documentation or would like to propose an improvement, please send an e-mail to docs@python.org describing the bug and where you found it. If you have a suggestion how to fix it, include that as well." If you don't feel like it, I'll do it?

Comment: @agf Please, do it. I don't feel very confident to propose any corrections.

Comment: @agf The only solution I can now come up with is to modify `sentinel` that it would implement some counter and raise it's own special Exception when needed.

Comment: @agf Also, if you can, please, write here, what solution you will have come up with for the pure Python equivalent to resemble the real function more closely.

Comment: I got a couple of emails from Python devs -- they said the "equivalent" code only needs to be "approximately correct", that the "equivalent" code is only an "illustration" and that they don't even consider it a bug, it's just an "implementation detail". If you want to see a pure Python implementation that should function identically, you can take a look at the [PyPy itertools implementation](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/6b92b3aa1cbb/pypy/module/itertools/interp_itertools.py#cl-624).

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue13003 has now been opened to track this, it's not clear if any action is going to be taken.

Comment: @agf As I think, the 'equivalent' code should be corrected since it may only be approximately correct in terms of time-memory efficiency, but has to be exactly the same in terms of functionality. Not re-raising 'IndexError' is really what I stumbled over some time ago. I can't say it was that bad since it was the reason I started this question and some follow-up questions, which turned out to be very good in terms of studying. But it may cause some difficulties other people who will be reading the documentation.

Comment: I agree with [Eli](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) (who created the bug report based on my email to the docs mailing list) that it needs to be made clear on the itertools documentation page page that the "equivalent" implementations differ in some details from the C implementations.

Comment: @agf By the way, the concerns laid out in this discussion have been reflected in the new docs: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest

Comment: Thanks for letting me know -- I wouldn't have seen it otherwise. I left a comment on the bug that they should change the resolution from "wont fix" to "fixed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `izip_longest_next` in the [code of `izip_longest`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a698ad2741da/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l3780), no sentinel is used.

Instead, CPython keeps track of how many of the iterators are still active with a counter, and stops when the number active reaches zero.

If an error occurs, it ends iteration as if there are no iterators still active, and allows the error to propagate.

The code:

```
            item = PyIter_Next(it);
            if (item == NULL) {
                lz->numactive -= 1;
                if (lz->numactive == 0 || PyErr_Occurred()) {
                    lz->numactive = 0;
                    Py_DECREF(result);
                    return NULL;
                } else {
                    Py_INCREF(lz->fillvalue);
                    item = lz->fillvalue;
                    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(lz->ittuple, i, NULL);
                    Py_DECREF(it);
                }
            }
```

The simplest solution I see:

```
def izip_longest_modified(*args, **kwds):
    # izip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
    fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
    class LongestExhausted(Exception):
        pass
    def sentinel(counter = ([fillvalue]*(len(args)-1)).pop):
        try:
            yield counter()         # yields the fillvalue, or raises IndexError
        except:
            raise LongestExhausted
    fillers = repeat(fillvalue)
    iters = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
    try:
        for tup in izip(*iters):
            yield tup
    except LongestExhausted:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks!
Still, I have to add, that to my mind it's not very good that an alleged **pure** Python **equivalent** has a slightly different functionality than the function itself. Strange, why did they put that equivalent this way. Anyway, to understand that code with `sentinel` was a good task for brain.

Comment: @ovgo Try it again? I edited it after I first posted it. It seems to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, it works! When I encountered that the first version that you provided didn't work, I started thinking and came up with the following code     def sentinel(fillvalue = fillvalue, counter = [0]):
              def ret():
            counter[0] += 1
            if counter[0] == len(args):
                raise LongestExhausted
            yield fillvalue
        return ret()

Comment: Oops. Seems, SO doesn't keep indentation in comments. I'll try to explain. I added counter = [0] so as to share this value with all the iterator returned by `sentinel` (as `list` is mutable). Still, curious is it OK to use counter = [0] in the parameter list. But I can't be put into the body if `sentinel` since [0] would be created gain and again on `sentinel` being called. And I didn't manage to put it just above the `sentinel` function since it lead to the problem of scopes and `global` keyword doesn't seem to let solve it.

Comment: @ovgo Look up [mutable default arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument). Function argument defaults are evaluated at definition time, so are the same every time the function is run. This only matters for mutable defaults. On Python 3, You could use the "nonlocal" keyword to put `counter` outside `sentinal`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already created a special question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394651/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-a-value-by-all-the-generators-created-by-a-function