# Problems with 'itertools' (Python) and Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-itertools

I'm trying to use the `itertools` module to use the `permutations` function but I'm having problems with my Mac.

I've been programing on another computer using linux and have no problem to use the code.

```
import itertools
ps = itertools.permutations(m)
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm working on a Mac:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'permutations'
```

Anyone knows how can I use 'itertools' in Mac?

Comment: Can you let us know which version of python you have installed?  `python --version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running python 2.5, which has no `permutations`.  It's new in 2.6.

You can find a python implementation of `permutations` you can use for 2.5 code in the python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: It's worth noting that some of the "equivalent to" code is _not actually equivalent_. See for example [this question about the `izip_longest` Python implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392902/izip-longest-in-itertools-how-does-rasing-indexerror-inside-the-iterator-work/7393480#7393480). You might be better off using the PyPy implementation, which is probably a fairly straightforward reimplementation of the C version in RPython.

Comment: @agf: I'll keep that in mind.. I've not looked too closely into these "equivalent implementations."

Comment: For permutations(), the pure python equivalent is algorithmically equivalent -- the C version was a direct translation but substituted C for-loops for Python's range() and reversed(); otherwise, the code is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions) says `New in version 2.6.`, so you might be running an older version. At least on my OSX Lion (Python 2.7.1) `from itertools import permutations` works.

Answer (score 0):

A typical library linker problem. A very useful guide for this problem(you should update the the linkages to python 2.6 and later -for system wide or just in IDE-) with additional tips, can be found [here](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/)